# disable lsp-mode for derived mode of haskell

Tags: lsp-mode, derived-mode

I am writing a major mode for a new programming language that looks very similar to Haskell, and so not surprisingly I am writing a derived mode from `haskell-mode`

```
(define-derived-mode foo-mode haskell-mode "foo mode"
  "Major mode for Foo"
...
)
```

Separately, I have `lsp-mode` enabled to run when I view a Haskell file in Emacs. Thus, every time I view a *.foo file in Emacs, `lsp-mode` is enabled with `haskell-language-server` as the `lsp`-backend.

I would like lsp to be disabled with I view a `*.foo` file (i.e. using the major mode `foo-mode`, but enabled when I view a `.*hs` file (i.e. using the major mode `haskell-mode`.)  Is this possible?

One solution I tried, which did not work: In the `.dirs-local.el` file of this project, I added this line:

```
((foo-mode . ((eval . (lsp-mode -1)))))
```

which I thought would disable lsp-mode whenever the major mode `foo` is enabled, but lsp is still enabled in this case.

Any suggestions?

Emacs version:

`GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2021-11-04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a wrapper like this and using it instead of `lsp` function should be good enough:

```
(defun my/lsp ()
  (unless (eq major-mode <REPLACE-ME-WITH-MAJOR-MODE>)
    (lsp)))
```